# Need to use the Class defined in 'Control' page in JQuery - MVC2

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

This is my control page, have class called AboutModels

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    AboutModels ObjAM = new AboutModels();
    List<PollOption> polloptions = new List<PollOption>();
    polloptions = ObjAM.dbValue();
    ViewData["polloptions"] = polloptions.ToList();
    return View();
}
```

I want to use this class into parse i mention (Need to Insert Object here)of this JQuery page

```
function Button1_onclick() {
    var currentWidth = parseInt($(".bgDiv").css("width")); //Getting the curent width.

    alert(currentWidth);
    $("**Need to Insert Object here**").css("width", currentWidth + 20 + "px");  // Adding 20px to the current width.
}
```

Please advise.

```
<asp:Content ID="aboutContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">.
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("jQuery page");
            $(".easy_editor").css("background-color", "Red"); // Here im setting the background color of the div with className changingDIV
            $(".easy_editor").css("width", 0);

            $('#myButton').live('click', function () {
                var currentWidth = parseInt($(".bgDiv").css("width")); //Getting the curent width.
                var abc = '<%=Model.AboutModels%>';
                alert(currentWidth);
                $(".easy_editor").css("width", currentWidth + 20 + "px");  //I want to use Hello_World_MVC.PollOption> class instead of easy_editor
            });
        });

    </script>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>

        <h2>About</h2>
        <p>
            <input value="Enter the value" />
            <input type="submit" value="ClickHere" />
            <%--
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
            --%>
        </p>

        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <% foreach (var obj in (List<Hello_World_MVC.PollOption>)ViewData["polloptions"]) { %>
                    //Here is my dynamic class I want to use this same class to the above jquery - Instead of .bgDiv
                    <%-- <div class="<%= obj.OptionID + "1" %>">--%>
                    <div class="bgDiv">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedObject" value="<%=obj.OptionID%>"/>
                        <%= obj.OptionName %>

                    </div>
                <% } //foreach %>
                <input id="myButton" type="button" />
            </td>
        <%-- <%=Html.CheckBox("<%=obj.OptionName%>",  --%>
        </tr>
        </table>
    <% } //using (endform) %>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Please post your view code - we need to know what html is going to be generated (or is generated).

Comment: I updated the question as per your request please advice

Comment: How do you know which class you should be selecting on the click? The button that the event is tied to is outside the loop, therefore it has any number of objects to choose from... do you want them all? Or...? On a side note, I've edited your code to show how you should be binding html click handlers using jQuery.

Comment: Thankx for your update - But i am not still clear.Please read my req n update me.

Comment: In the 1st box - I have gave you the control page of my MVC page

Comment: In the 2nd box i have added the JQery code - Here(in jquery) i need to use the class(AboutModels ObjAM = new AboutModels();).This AboutModel is the class i created in Model page and it returns list of variables

Comment: You're doing this `$("**Need to Insert Object here**")` and you want `<div class="<%= obj.OptionID + "1" %>">` put in there? But the thing is, you are going to have multiple divs... so how do you know which one you want?

Comment: The value <%= obj.OptionID + "1" %> is come from DB - Dynamically im creating check box and dev and the class name set using option id.

Comment: All this funtion working but for the <div class=""> class name im setting dynamically and need to set the background for all this div in runtime. so im trying to use jquery to set the background values.but im not familar.so please advice

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand what exactly you are after... but I'll try my best.

If you do something like this:

```
<% foreach (var obj in (List<Hello_World_MVC.PollOption>)ViewData["polloptions"]) { %>
    <div id="checkBoxDiv<%= obj.OptionID %>" class="bgDiv">
        <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedObject" value="<%=obj.OptionID%>"/>
        <%= obj.OptionName %>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

You should get a whole bunch of divs with different ids (e.g. 'checkBoxDiv1', 'checkBoxDiv2', ... 'checkBoxDivN') but they will all have the same class - 'bgDiv'.

Now if you want to get all the divs in jQuery you would do:

```
$('.bgDiv')
```

But if you want an individual div, you can use the id. E.g.

```
$('#checkBoxDiv4')
```

But if you want to get the checkBox by id inside the button click, there needs to be more context because the button is outside of the loop and doesn't have any idea of each input div.

**EDIT**: To increase the width of each div by 10px starting at 10px you can do this:

```
$('.bgDiv').each(function (index) {
    var newWidth = (index + 1) * 10;
    $(this).width(newWidth);
});
```

Comment: thankx for your help.. I undertand your prog.. I need one more help.. How i can set the width for the <div> dynamically.I mean <Div> dynamically generting as per the <Div> class name or using ID I need to set the width by using priority.

Comment: For EX:i have Div1,Div2,Div3 in a property - I need to set Div1 = width:10px,Div2 = width:20px,Div3 = width:30px. This Div1,Div2 are i am generating dynamically and value of the width also i am setting dynamically.  Please advice

Comment: Ok, so that's exactly what you want to do? Just increase the width by 10px for each div?

Comment: No.. I want to update the width dynamically.. just to explain you i said like that.. but i need to update by the value from DB